# How to avoid duplicate lines output by TestNG/Maven/Surefire?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My multi-project build output is filled with blocks that look like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.454 sec

Results :

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Is there any way to reduce verbosity so all I get is the single line for each project, i.e.

```
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.454 sec
```

Comment: The first line with the elapsed time can be written several times...the question what is the real problem with that?

Comment: I want to view the entire build output without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The following should help:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
          <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <!-- add listeners/reporters you want-->
        <property>
          <name>listener</name>
          <value>com.mycompany.MyResultListener,com.mycompany.MyAnnotationTransformer,com.mycompany.MyMethodInterceptor</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>reporter</name>
          <value>listenReport.Reporter</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

From: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html